# MAX function always returning 0 in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a column A, such that the first row value is 1, and the second row value is:

```
=MAX(IF(A1:A2<>"";A1:A2))
```

This displays a 0 in A2; why doesn't it show 1, as 1 is the maximum of the range selected? And how can I get it to give me the actual maximum value of the range?

```
=MAX(A1:A2)
```

This displays 0 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When entering this formula, you should get a "Circular reference" warning.

`A2` contains a formula referring to  itself, this is known as a *circular reference*.

The first time Excel finds a circular reference, it displays a warning message. Click OK or close the message window. If you are on Excel for Windows, click Help to go to this help topic.

When you close the message, Excel displays either a zero or the last calculated value in the cell.

To fix this problem, move the formula to a cell outside of the range of the formula.